# Can you give away or destroy artifacts?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

I have filled all of my art slots but still have several dig sites available. When one of them was completed I wasn't given the option to create an artifact because there were no available slots, thus forcing me to create a free landmark for my rival.

I have two buildings that lack the theming bonus. I'd like to make room for new artifacts in the hopes that I'd get lucky and find a match. Is it possible to give away or destroy artifacts or turn them into units?

**Note:** I know that I can trade them, but that doesn't make room for more. I am founding a new city as it looks like my Tourism rate isn't high enough to overcome Russia's culture rate from conquering their continent. However, I don't want to found too many new cities and slow my social policy rate. I have built all buildings that provide art slots in my current four cities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to destroy great works in this case, they can only be destroyed if you capture them from an opposing civ. In the future you should just not make excess archeologists. If you do want to prevent your opponents from excavating an area (and have open borders with them), you can park a worker or other unit on the square where the archeological site is. You can also consider constructing a wonder with artifact slots, if there is one remaining.

Comment: I believe you're correct since I found no way to destroy them, but do you happen to have a definitive source?

Comment: @DavidHarkness No, but if I see any I will edit the question.

Comment: @DavidHarkness I've looked, and an actual source will be difficult to come across. There's no mention of it in the civlopedia, the wiki, or on the civ fanatics forum.

Comment: If "there is no way to destroy great works in this case", then what will happen, if I make a new city, buy museum there, move artifacts to it and raze it with nukes? Will the artifacts automatically move back to the previous City at the moment of destroying the new city? If yes, then what if I make an arts with Great Artist before the nuking and take away all the free spaces in the old city?